# How to set SelectedItem property to current clicked element in multiselection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, multi-select, selecteditem

I have a technical and philosophy question which is described in following scenario.

Scenario: I have a Listview. I multiselected several items from a Listview with holding left ctrl and clicking left mouse button. Items are selected. Then still holding left ctrl I click on one of selected items again. I want SelectedItem proeprty to set on this item.

Unfortunately SelectedItem property is set on first item (standard behaviour of SelectedItem property). But what I want to achieve is set SelectedItem property every single time I click. How can I achieve this funcionality? I hope I explained clearly what I want to achieve :)

Comment: It's certainly possible, but be aware that you will have to explain this non-standard behaviour to the users of your application.

Comment: So if it is possible could you show me how to achive that?

Comment: No sorry, that would be a lot of programming work that you should do.

Comment: I do not want code from you. I only want sequence of steps to achieve it. What should i use?

Comment: When you say, *"If I click on one of the selected items again..."* do you mean in the same session, while you have `Ctrl` pressed? Or some time later? Also, don't ask a yes/no question (*"Is it possible?"*) if you want more than a "yes" or a "no"...

Comment: Ok, next time I will ask my question in a better way:) I meant in this same session.

Comment: You can edit your question with more information, so you get a better response (click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53835829/edit) link below. Otherwise I'm afraid this may get closed.

Comment: I ve edited my question.

Comment: I have no idea what would happen if you set the selecteditem property from code. It could mess up selecteditems. Maybe you should consider an attached behaviour with a separate dependency property of your own. You could then just set it when the user clicks - or whatever your requirement is exactly

Comment: I have solved my problem with manipulating SelectionChanged and MouseLeftButtonUp event triggers :)